# How to enable natural scrolling for Logitech T650 touchapd on Wayland?

Tags: touchpad, wayland, logitech, libinput

I've been using a Logitech T650 while running running X11, and have used the following command to set natural-scrolling:

```bash
xinput set-prop "Logitech Rechargeable Touchpad T650" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

I recently switched to Wayland, and haven't been able to figure out what the corresponding command would be for Wayland. Trying to use `xinput` produces an error, and the `man xinput` docs say:

> In most instances, using xinput with an Xwayland device is indicative of a bug in a shell script and xinput will print a warning. Use the Wayland Compositor's native device configuration methods instead.

Does anyone know what these "native device configuration methods" are? System settings isn't it for external devices, which don't show up there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, thanks to the [KDE discord](https://discuss.kde.org/c/help/6) (which is great) - posting in case it helps anyone else.

Simple answer: Wayland will now detect the Logitech T650, and there's a drop-down in the Touchpad settings with which you can select it (and any external device that `libinput` detects). Hooray!

If you do want to modify it programmatically, from @jpetso, KDE developer:

> The programmatic way would be through D-Bus calls. KWin exposes all of its input devices on the session (user) bus, the service’s bus name being org.kde.KWin, object path org/kde/KWin/InputDevice/event (one for every input device, with  starting at 0) and interface org.kde.KWin.InputDevice. You’d want to find your device by looking at the name property, and then set the naturalScroll property of the same event D-Bus object to true. I like to use qdbus to explore this with a GUI (it can also set these properties), or busctl via CLI if it needs to go into a script.

[Original post](https://discuss.kde.org/t/how-to-access-libinput-properties-in-wayland-for-an-external-touchpad/11730/2?u=andrew_g)